# Windows 2003 Server Uninstall DNS component doesn't remove dns.exe

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003

I have a windows 2003 server that has AD installed with DNS.  When i uninstall DNS from the control panel->Add/Remove Programs->Add/Remove Windows Components->Networking Services, the file C:\windows\system32\dns.exe remains.  I cannot delete it, some process re-adds it within a few seconds.  Can anyone explain why this file does not uninstall when the DNS component is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to delete this file?
Installing or removing features from windows 2003 are just activating or deactivating them. If the files are not present they will be copied to the system, but on remove those files wont be removed. For what? If you remove the DNS service, the server don't act as name server and don't give any answers.

Comment: Yes, i do understand that the components are simply "deactivated" however this is a compliancy thing.  The dns.exe left behind after "uninstalling" could be a vulnerable version.  Yes, it can be argued since its deactivated, it doesn't matter, but lets say it does, then the applicable MS patch will not install because it fails the prequisite checks.

Comment: MS patch all files regardless you have them active or not in this case. It is a difference if you install a sql server or office or talking about the system. security issues will be patched, always. And even if not, a not running system can't be compromised in this way. Starting the dns.exe if there is a exploit e.g. won't work if the system not set it up properly.

Comment: In this particular case, the patch for MS09-008 (i dont have the KB number handy) will not install unless DNS component is installed. The patch fails if DNS is not installed.  I understand your point about if its not active, however from a compliance standpoint it causes some unneeded exceptions / explainations.  I guess the answer is "deal" with it, or talk to MS directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove DNS from a 2003 server o/s follow these steps:

- Stop sharing files.
- Remove DNS by typing "dcpromo" in Run.(you get run by pressing winkey+R)
- Remove it by going to manage your server.

Comment: consider adding it as a comment, not as an answer